# CSS IE Compatibility

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am using the following `CSS` code which works perfect with `Chrome` but not with `IE` browsers

```
.collapse{
    display:block;
}
.collapse + input[type="checkbox"]{
  display:none;
}
.collapse + input[type="checkbox"] + *{
  display:none;
}
.collapse + input[type="checkbox"]:checked + *{
  display:block;
}
```

Sample Code [Fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/Zr5Nf/)

Comment: which version of IE you are trying to support

Comment: I tried both IE 10 and 11

Comment: please provide some more code .... Use fiddle

Comment: @KillerR [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Zr5Nf/)

Comment: Works fine on my IE 11...

Comment: @Itay in `IE` gives me only the collapse state

Comment: Are you be any chance on an older `Document mode` on the emulation settings?

Comment: and how to check that

Comment: Press `F12` and go to the `Emulation` Tab (Ctrl+8). Make sure that the mode of your browser is `Document mode: Edge(Default), Browser profile: Desktop, User agent string: Default`

Comment: Also, make sure that you're using the doctype tag `<!DOCTYPE html>` so the browser knows that it's supposed to target html5.

Comment: @Avisari In a fiddle, you don't have to worry about doctypes, so that's not it.

Comment: @Itay yes it worked by following your provided steps , but how to enforce this changes in all `IE` user's machine

Comment: @user2079954 This is the default configuration, so you don't have to worry about it. You've probably changed it in the past and forgot about it.

Comment: @Itay many thanks for your help, I just replaced the line `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Itay many thanks for your help, I just replaced the line `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` with `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />`

Comment: You're welcome. If you have published this piece of code earlier, we could have helped you faster :)